# R# Plugin test: How to specify context action with bracket in name

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, resharper-plugins

I created a composite context action that returns a couple of intentions with the following texts:

- [Tag] Action
- Second Action

Now I'm trying to cover this action by tests. I did everything by guidelines, but I'm not able to identify the first action using the `caret` notation.

I've tried the following options:

- `{caret:[Tag]:Action}`
- `{caret:Tag:Action}`

Note of them worked :(

If I do the same for the `Second Action`, everything is fine. Likely, issue is related to brackets.

I don't want to change name of the action. Could you advice how to specify the action with brackets?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I've found the following workaround:

1. In data file specify alias for action: `{caret:TagAction}`.
2. Override `SelectItem` method and adjust attribute

   ```
   protected override IBulbAction SelectItem(SetFrozenAttributeAction contextAction, string attribute, ITextControl textControl)
   {
     if (attribute == "TagAction") attribute = "[Tag] Action";
     return base.SelectItem(contextAction, attribute, textControl);
   }
   ```

If you know better way - suggest it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the brackets. I don't know why, but when it encounters the opening brace `{`, it doesn't read up to a closing brace `}`, but reads a set of chars that it deems are "valid", and then stops when it hits the first non-valid char. The valid chars are `char.IsLetter`, `char.IsDigit` and `$`, `(`, `)`, `,` `-`, `.`, `/`, `\`. But not `[` or `]` - so your `{caret:[Tag] Action}` would just read `{caret:` and then stop.

Your workaround seems like the best bet!